# Dynamic link to different list views within a Lightning:card component footer - Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Here is the scenario... I'm trying to create a link, within a lightning:card footer section, to a list view based on the current user.

So, basically, if a field on the user's record is set to one value, I want the link to point to one list view, if it's set to another value I want the link to point to another list view.

I'm having a hard time using the lightning:navigation to make it dynamic, as it looks like force:navigateToList is no longer supported.

I couldn't find any samples online.

Any help?